# How do I correctly access the user's home directory from a grunt template?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'd like to use template in a Grunt file selection to copy a file to a user's home directory (don't ask why).

```
files: [ 
  {src: ['build/my_file.txt'], dest: "<%= grunt.process.HOME %>/my_file.txt"}
]
```

But this probably isn't right because then I get this:

`Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'env' of undefined)`

HOWEVER, if I force a javascript statement to be evaluated it works fine:

```
files: [ 
  {src: ['build/my_file.txt'], dest: "<%= grunt.process.HOME + '' %>/my_file.txt"}
]
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the [os-homedir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-homedir) or [userhome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/userhome) packages.  If you don't want to use them directly, their source code is fairly concise and illustrate a cross-platform process for getting the home directory.

They mostly use `process.env.HOME` on Linux/MacOS, and `process.env.USERPROFILE` on Windows, but also have some logic to make something when those are missing.